# Getting to use Power Within more than once?

Tags: dark-souls

Is there a way to increase the amount of times that I can use Power Within before resting at bonfires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without entering NG+ and finding the spell again.

In Dark Souls 2, they included a feature that increases spell uses when you increase your attunement enough, but in Dark Souls 1, the only way you can increase spell castings is to find and attune another spell.

Side note: You can use the [Lingering Dragoncrest Ring](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Lingering_Dragoncrest_Ring) to increase the duration of the spell.

For clarification - the [Dusk Crown Ring](http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Dusk+Crown+Ring) does grant additional castings, but only an additional 50%, rounded down, at the cost of half of your health. So in this case, not only is it redundant, but it just makes things harder with no payoff.